# Why should I use "xor dx,dx" and why the result of the division is not in the specified register? - Assembly (.COM)

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16

I was supposed to write code in Assembly (.COM) that computes the given data according to the formula (b * b - 4 * a) / d. The program works fine, but I got 2 questions that I need to answer, but unfortunately I don't know the exact solution.

1. Why would this program without `xor dx, dx` not work?
2. Why the result of the division is not necessarily in the AL register?

> ```
>                .MODEL  TINY   
>
> Code            SEGMENT           
>               
>                 ORG     100h  
>                 ASSUME  CS:Code, DS:Code, SS:Code 
>
> Start:                            
>               jmp Begin   
>               
>               a               EQU      20         
>               b               EQU      10         
>               d               EQU      3          
>               Result          DB       ?          
>
> Begin:                                            
>               mov     al, b               
>               mov     bl, b               
>               mul     bl                  
>               mov     bx, ax              
>                                           
>            
>               mov     al, a               
>               mov     ah, 4               
>               mul     ah                          
>                                           
>               
>               sub     bx, ax              
>               mov     ax, bx                          
>               
>               xor     dx, dx                                  
>               mov     bx, d                           
>               div     bx                          
>                                           
>               mov     Result, al                              
>
>               mov     ax, 4C00h           
>               int     21h                 
>                                           
>
> Code           ENDS                           
>                 END    Start
> ```

Please help me with answering these 2 questions. Thank you!

Comment: Please refer to the instruction set reference as to how `div` works.  Note that it divides `dx:ax` by its operand, so if you don't clear `dx` beforehand, you'll divide whatever content is in there, too (and likely cause a division overflow).  As for your second question, the result is in `ax`, not `al`.

Comment: Thank you for answer! Could I still ask why "mov Result, al" works if the result is in ax?

Comment: Recall that `AL` refers to the low 8 bit of `AX`.

Comment: Well. Now I know, thank you again!

Comment: If you `xor` a register with itself, you've set the register's value to zero. This is usually preferred over `mov dx,0` since `xor dx,dx` doesn't need to embed the 0 into the machine code to get the job done, making your program's file size smaller. However, if you need to clear a register without altering the flag register, you have to use `mov dx,0`.